# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'voice.mp3'

Tags: python, bots, chatbot

I am trying to create a ChatBot, VA, in Python, for receiving audio output I have the packages gtts(google text to speech), playsound, and have used system os to save the audio file before playing.

The Code is below:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import playsound
import os #to save the file
import time


def speak(text):#this defines the function SPEAK and creates the command for its use
           tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
           filename = "voice.mp3"
           tts.save(filename) #saves the audio file
           playsound.playsound(filename)

       #function ends here
```

To play the audio I use the function in the following way:

```
>>>speak("I am speaking this text")
```

The above ^^^ works perfectly fine, but when I use multiple statements like:

```
>>>speak("I am saying this")
>>>speak("And also this!")
```

It gives an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'voice.mp3'
```

Which I figured was due to matching names of audio files. But then when I tried to use a loop to change the number every time, it still showed the error after playing the audio for a specified number of times. Can someone please give me a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to overwrite the file `voice.mp3` from a different call of the function. What you need to do is delete the voice.mp3 file after you play the file. So:

```py
def speak(text):#this defines the function SPEAK and creates the command for its use
       tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
       filename = "voice.mp3"
       tts.save(filename) #saves the audio file
       playsound.playsound(filename)
       os.remove(filename)
```

Make sure that you are not storing the file in a sensitive location, and your working directory is somewhere in documents or downloads or something.

Comment: Thank You for putting in your time to answer this question, while I was researching I found this way and it works.

Comment: Awesome! Glad too help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a file permission issue when the function is running it is overwriting the existing file

I would check that the user/group which is running the code has permission to read/write

How this is done depends if you are using windows, mac or linux